# Will i loose the committed data if i change my PC

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I have some issue with my laptop. It will get replaced but i have data which is committed on all the branches and not pushed to remote. Will I loose all the branches data?

Comment: If the disk is still working, remove it and copy over the files to safe storage. There are simple USB disk enclosures which allow you to mount the loose disk as external storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will lose the data. Committed changes are stored in local repo .git folder. You will need to push to an upstream server or take a copy of the .git folder to not lose the data.